# Answers that are works in progress

Tags: discussion, answers

Like this one: [Effect of potato water on bread (early experiment results)](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/46026/effect-of-potato-water-on-bread/46037#46037)

It's not a complete answer yet, and it's just kind of hanging there. I'll be able to improve the answer with continued experimentation.

I kind of like the idea of editing as I go, partly because because some information is better than no information and partly to avoid duplication of effort. I also get the benefit of helpful comments from other users during my experimentation.

There is also the chance that someone will come along with a really stellar answer. That would be great.

So I'm leaning towards thinking this kind of thing is OK (I guess especially in this case since it's my question), but I want to make sure I'm not doing something vaguely "wrong".

Comments?

Answer (score 2):

We have specific guidelines around this. The rule is: [answer the question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer). Don't add [placeholder answers](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/q/769/41) - they will be generally be downvoted, flagged, and/or deleted.

A "work in progress" is completely fine - **if** it actually answers the question in its current state. It may be an incomplete answer, or an untested answer, or in need of improvement - those are all fine, although they might attract downvotes. But in order to avoid tit must actually **be** an answer - that's the key if you want to avoid deletion.

Comment: Great answer, but it begs a question. In your opinion, is that particular answer an *answer*?

Comment: @Jolenalaska I would consider it one, even though you specifically mention that it's from another source. Falls under the heading of "incomplete".

Comment: @logophobe Thanks, I added my first experiment, so it's improved now and I feel fine about it. My next few loaves will add to the info and hopefully the answer will someday feel *complete* :)